# DRF w/Child & Parent Relationships Make Get & Post Different

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using DRF for the first time and trying to understand how to make GET return the full information about a child including full parent information. I want POST should accept child information and either parent ID or parent name when creating a child.

Feels like there is a simple solution here that is eluding me.

models.py

```
class TestParent(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='ballerz')

class TestChild(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(TestParent, related_name='test_children', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializers.py

```
class TestParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField()
    class Meta:
        model = TestParent
        fields = ('id', 'name',)

class TestChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parent = TestParentSerializer(many=False, allow_null=False)

    class Meta:
        model = TestChild
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'parent')
```

views.py

```
class TestParentModelSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = "Parent API"
        self.description = ""

    queryset = TestParent.objects.all()    
    serializer_class = TestParentSerializer

class TestChildModelSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = "Child API"
        self.description = ""

    queryset = TestChild.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestChildSerializer

    filter_fields = ('id', 'name')
    search_fields = filter_fields
```

GET returns what I want and expect:

```
{
    "id": "515ff558-d0e2-4fdd-bdeb-9c5acf459687",
    "name": "Test Child 01",
    "parent": {
        "id": "1dc3d3ce-b45a-46b4-9b62-a227949a6d87",
        "name": "Foo Parent"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. Do you want `TestChildModelSet` to save **Child** with either the **name** or the **id** of **parent**?

Comment: Exactly.

(sorry for it being unclear.)

Comment: Can you share your `urls.py`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if there is something inside DRF, that will help you. I can suggest to override *retriev*e method

```
class TestChildModelSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        parent = TestParent.object.get(id=instance.parent.id)
        return Response({"id":instance.id, "name":instance.name, "parent": {"id":parent.id, "name":parent.name}})
```

I haven't tested that code, but hope, that it works